# Variable (h1) out of scope?

Tags: java, scope

In an question that answer is "Compilation Fails", because in the go method h1 is out of scope.  h1 looks public to me, Can someone explain why is it out of scope?  When can a method access other variables?

```
public class Happy {
  int id;
  Happy(int i) { id = i; }
  public static void main(String [] args) {
    Happy h1 = new Happy(1);
    Happy h2 = h1.go(h1);
    System.out.println(h2.id);
  }
  Happy go(Happy h) {
    Happy h3 = h;
    h3.id = 2;
    h1.id = 3;
    return h1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line defines

```
Happy h1 = new Happy(1);
```

This is inside the scope of `main(String[] args)`

which is why you can't access it outside the `{` `}` of main.

Comment: Anything declared in main can't be accessed anywhere else? Is there a way to access objects declared in main?

Comment: @mc805 You can access object declared in `main()` by also passing them somewhere in a scope you object can access.

Comment: @mc805 In your case you are already doing this as `h` and `h3` point to the object `h1` in main, as you passed a reference to it.

Comment: @mc805 main() is accessible to everything, but local variables are only local and accessible to the method it is in.

Comment: definitely makes sense now... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Happy go(Happy h) {
        Happy h3 = h;
        h3.id = 2;
        h1.id = 3;
        return h1;
      }
```

h1 used in above method is out of scope.

You are creating h1 object inside main method but trying to access it in go method where h1 is not visible.

You can use it like below:-

```
 static Happy h1 = new Happy(1);

      public static void main(String [] args) {

        Happy h2 = h1.go(h1);
        System.out.println(h2.id);
      }
      Happy go(Happy h) {
        Happy h3 = h;
        h3.id = 2;
        h1.id = 3;
        return h1;
      }
```

Comment: Given `h1` is `this` and `h` in `go` adding it as a `static` as well is probably not needed. ;)